# Aspose.Word MailMerge FieldMergingCallback set font size

Tags: c#, aspose, aspose.words

Is it possible in FieldMergingCallback retrieve the field size, calculation of the font size and change font size for merging text? 
In my template, I have table with fixed size cell. The table can not grow. 
So when I put a long text into the cell, I would like the font to be smaller when the text does not fit. 
The Fit-text option in the table settings in Word, does not work as I would like.

Comment: You can calculate coordinates of valid Nodes by using the classes available in [Aspose.Words.Layout Namespace](https://apireference.aspose.com/net/words/aspose.words.layout/). Secondly, a complete field in a Word document is a complex structure consisting of a field start character, field code, field separator character, field result and field end character. You can adjust the Font size of all Run nodes which are enclosed in between field start and field end characters. https://apireference.aspose.com/net/words/aspose.words/inline/properties/font. I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.

Comment: Your post is very useful. Thanks. I have another problem, this time with the change of the font. Could you take a look?
[question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51043422/aspose-word-mailmerge-set-font-in-paragraph)

Comment: Please see my answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/51055421/4952051

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before performing Mail Merge, you can use the following code to apply some Font formatting to all Run nodes inside Merge Field:

```
foreach (Field field in doc.Range.Fields)
{
    if (field.Type.Equals(Aspose.Words.Fields.FieldType.FieldMergeField))
    {
        Node currentNode = field.Start;
        bool isContinue = true;
        while (currentNode != null && isContinue)
        {
            if (currentNode.NodeType.Equals(NodeType.FieldEnd))
            {
                FieldEnd end = (FieldEnd)currentNode;
                if (end == field.End)
                    isContinue = false;
            }

            if (currentNode.NodeType.Equals(NodeType.Run))
            {
                // Specify Font formatting here
                Run run = ((Run)currentNode);
                run.Font.Size = 6;
            }

            Node nextNode = currentNode.NextPreOrder(currentNode.Document);
            currentNode = nextNode;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope, this helps. I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.