# Aspose.Word MailMerge set font in paragraph

Tags: c#, aspose, aspose.words

In FieldMergingCallback.FieldMerging and I set font to all Runs in Node =>

```
 public void FieldMerging(FieldMergingArgs args)
    {
        if (args.FieldValue.ToString().Length > 100)
        {
            var node = args.Field.Start.ParentNode.ParentNode;
            if (node is Shape)
            {
                var runlist = node.GetChildNodes(NodeType.Run, true);
                foreach (Run run in runlist)
                {
                    run.Font.Size = 6;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But in result pdf is:
[image]

Why is the font smaller than the third word?

Comment: Have your changes actually made a diffrernce?  What does it look like if you dont set the font size?

Comment: @Neil 1 - yes, if I comment //run.Font.Size = 6; all text in line is like two first word.

Comment: I wonder if there is some other settings that overrides font size?  Maybe a paragraph style that makes the first 2 words in a paragraph a particular size?

Comment: No, this is pure Word document with many MergeFields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before performing mail merge, you can use the following code to apply same formatting to all Run nodes inside a merge field.

```
Document doc = new Document("D:\\temp\\input.docx");

foreach (Field field in doc.Range.Fields)
{
    if (field.Type.Equals(Aspose.Words.Fields.FieldType.FieldMergeField))
    {
        Node currentNode = field.Start;
        bool isContinue = true;
        while (currentNode != null && isContinue)
        {
            if (currentNode.NodeType.Equals(NodeType.FieldEnd))
            {
                FieldEnd end = (FieldEnd)currentNode;
                if (end == field.End)
                    isContinue = false;
            }

            if (currentNode.NodeType.Equals(NodeType.Run))
            {
                Run run = ((Run)currentNode);
                run.Font.Size = 6;
            }

            Node nextNode = currentNode.NextPreOrder(currentNode.Document);
            currentNode = nextNode;
        }
    }
}

doc.Save("D:\\Temp\\18.6.docx");
```

Hope, this helps. I work with Aspose as Developer Evangelist.